# The "Maybe" monad and simple "try/catch" solution

Tags: oop, monads, option-type

I have a question about using the "Maybe" monad in object-oriented languages.
Namely, the "spirit" of using the monad says instead of writing code like:

```
return getUser(id).group.groupOwner.name
```

which might fail at any point because of null pointer exception, we write it instead:

```
return Maybe.of(getUser(id))
       .map( user => user.group )
       .map( group => groupOwner )
       .map( owner => name )
       .orSome( "No Owner" )
```

This is all clear to me and sounds reasonable to write programs like that.

But then I got a thought: assuming the language we are writing with has got a `NullPointerException` class, then why not to write the above example like that:

```
try {
    return getUser(id).group.groupOwner.name
}
catch( NullPointerException e ) {
    return "No Owner"
}
```

This code also has a clear happy-path and seems much simpler than the code with the monad.

So, is there any use of the "Maybe" monad in OOP? Or is there an advantage of the monad I didn't consider of?

Comment: You just applied a functional idiom to arbitrary imperative code. That doesn't make sense. If you are comfortable with `try/catch`, which is nothing more than goto in disguise, than you shouldn't use functional idioms. Stick with one paradigm and you are fine.

Comment: There is a fundamental misunderstanding of the point of Monads.  The whole first half is wrong, so the foundations are wrong, so the assumptions are wrong.  Read up on monads from people like Mark Seemann.  It's too much for a comment or answer on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really *need* the maybe monad in a traditional OOP language (say java). Just like your example, the try/catch block can accomplish the same thing. That being said, using the maybe monad (Or similarly, the either monad) in a language like Haskell is for the best since it encapsulates any side effects.

Another way I like to think about the maybe monad is to compare it with checked exceptions in java. See [this](https://techblog.bozho.net/checked-and-unchecked-exceptions-in-java/) blog for more info. Basically, just like the checked exception, a function returning a monad "forces" the programmer to think about what to do on error. In my opinion, this design help Haskell achieve "Once your code compiles it usually works" status. See [this](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-that-some-people-say-that-if-a-Haskell-program-compiles-it-probably-works#:%7E:text=Programmer%20since%201987-,Originally%20Answered%3A%20Why%20is%20that%20some%20people%20say%20that%20%22if,correct%20(for%20small%20programs).) quora answer for more on that topic.

Comment: Wrong and wrong.  `try/catch` does not accomplish the same thing as a Monad, and you absolutely do *need* to use the Maybe Monad in any language.  Also, "Traditional OOP" isn't a thing.  There have always been different viewpoints on what OO is, and most languages that were built with OO in mind are widely used with multiple paradigms.